# How to skip over child element with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm looking to scrape just the job description from this page: https://www.aha.io/company/careers/current-openings/customer_success_specialist_project_management_us

I'd like to get all of the text and HTML inside the div with the class of `"container py2 content job"`, EXCEPT the button. It's in an `<a>` tag with the class of `"btn btn-large btn-secondary"`.

I've got two different xpath selectors that I thought should work, but don't. The first doesn't exclude the button and the second gets rid of all of the other HTML, which I'd like to keep.

```
response.xpath('//div[@class ="container py2 content job"] 
[not(parent::a/@class="btn btn-large btn-secondary")]').extract()

response.xpath('//div[@class ="container py2 content 
job"]/descendant::text()[not(parent::a/@class="btn btn-large btn- 
secondary")]').extract()
```

Neither is scraping all of the HTML in the div minus what's inside the a tag. I'm hoping there's something simple that I'm missing, but I can't find what I'm looking for in the documentation.

Comment: Does my answer not solve your problem? Its a kind of hackish way of skipping an element, but when its an element like this and not something like every other row its hard. If anybody has a better idea feel free to edit my answer but it seems to solve the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

```
job_html = response.css('div.content *').extract()
job_html = [x for x in job_html if "Apply now" not in x]
print(job_html)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! The challenge is that there's a button at the top of the listing as well that I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: Try that see if that does what you need